# Error -- Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, swift, custom-keyboard, xcode6.4

I am working on a custom keyboard and if i include this code in my class the i got the error:

```
let isPad = UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad

Error - Command/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1
```

I need this code because when user runs iPhone app (like instagram) on iPad, I need to load iPhone keyboard preset and use its geometry. I have try below code but it is not a solution:

if  UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == .Pad
  {

}

So please share if anyone have any solution.

[image: Error screen shot]

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Still no solution.

Comment: @Maria I think UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad is not supported with a type of UIInputViewController class it is supported to UIViewController class .I still not get any solution for that but i use another method for it may be it is useful for you                                                                                override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    }                     this method give me exact size of default keyboard in some attempt so i use it and do my code according to it..

Comment: My issue was that I accidently left old           UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == .Pad instead of proper UIDevice.currentDevice() in one file. I used xctool to find that https://github.com/facebook/xctool because xcode error message was not very informative.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad {

    // iPad Stuff
}

else if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {

    // iPhone Stuff
}
```

---

**EDIT**

**Swift 3**

```
if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {

    // iPad Stuff
}

else if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {

    // iPhone Stuff
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. I've no idea why this issue started - UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM seemed to work fine previously.